# How to add a legal disclaimer to an iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store, expo

I need to have a legal disclaimer for an iOS app, how can I add this?

In appstoreconnect.apple.com I have an option to set the Privacy Policy URL, but that's the only legal conditions I can see.

Not sure if it matters but my project uses React Native / Expo.

Comment: I just did a google search for your exact question: `How to add a legal disclaimer to an iOS app?` and came up with many, many articles discussing it. That's probably your best route to guidance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would you seem that you need to manually make a custom screen.